# Create a Custom Print Dialog before printing

Tags: printing, dialog

Here is my problem:

I want to create a virtual "driver" that creates a custom dialog.
In this dialog there should be 2 buttons: "Color" and "Black".

Depending on this decision I want to send the print to a "real" printer driver to print it on my color / not color printer.

Is it possible to create such a dialog? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with Printer++.

I wrote a processor class that asks me if I want to print Color or not and depending on my anwser I send the file with RawPrinterHelper to a real printer